# problems with pointer in function

Tags: c, arrays

I encountered erratic behavior when initializing array in function.

I have an uninitialized pointer below:

```
int *arr;
```

And I am passing it to a function for initialization.

```
init_arr(&arr);

void init_arr(int **arr)
{
*arr = (int *) calloc(10, sizeof **arr);
}
```

The pointer is initilized, and when I try get items *arr[2] and larger I get the error:

```
Cannot access memory to address 0x0
```

The source code was compiled using gcc version 4.8.4

Comment: get item `(*arr)[2]` perhaps?

Comment: Try (*arr)[2] and this works! thanks! I need to be careful. Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure, but believe `(*arr)[2]` is equivalent to just `arr[2]`, as the compiler treats a pointer as an array.

Comment: do not cast the returned value from `calloc()` why? because 1) the returned value is a defined as `void *` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) the cast just clutters the code and can create a real headache when debugging or maintaining the code.

Comment: user3629249, I will turn attention to it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of expression

```
 *arr[2]
```

you have to use

```
 arr[2]
```

You allocated an array of 10 integers. So to acces an element of the array it is enough to write for example `arr[2]`.

If you mean an access of an element of the allocated array inside the function `init` then you have to write

```
 ( *arr )[2]
```